# Power and external display issues with Ubuntu 19.10 on Lenovo P1 Gen2 (Quadro T2000)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, lenovo, intel-graphics, 19.10

I have a Lenovo P1 Gen2 (with a Quadro T2000/PCIe/SSE2) with a freshly installed Ubuntu 19.10.

I also have a Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 Dock, with 2 monitors connected to it - one via DisplayPort and one via HDMI.

**My goal**: I'd like to have `prime-select on-demand` powering off the nVidia GPU until it is needed, and the exterior monitors working consistently.

I sadly encounter several issues with the configuration above:

1. The P1 Gen2 has a hybrid GPU solution, with a low-power Intel UHD Graphics 630 graphics adapter running except when the GPU is actually required. This works fine on Windows 10. However, using `prime-select intel` does not work as expected and does not power off the nVidia GPU. This means that the power consumption is very high, and the battery lasts about 50-70% less compared to what it could last without the GPU. I don't always need the GPU, after all, especially not when I'm on battery power. 
   Now, the following [hack](https://github.com/stockmind/dell-xps-9560-ubuntu-respin/issues/8#issuecomment-389292575) does achieve the desired result - it actually turns off the GPU and everything works perfectly when the laptop is undocked from the Lenovo dock.
2. The solution for issue #1, using `prime-select intel` (or even `prime-select on-demand`), causes a new issue - the external monitors connected to the Thunderbolt 3 Dock are not detected at all. It took me a while to figure out this was one of two culprits - I thought it might've been something related to DisplayLink (apparently not necessary at all), to X11 vs Wayland, to the nVidia drivers, an X11 configuration of some sort, gdm3 vs lightdm, extended boot time to detect the displays, etc. But no, the only two requirements to get the external monitors to work are:
   to set `prime-select nvidia` and to disable *Secure Boot*, and then to reboot. Naturally, by using `prime-select nvidia` the power consumption is very high.

I also noted that when booting either with *Secure Boot* on or with `prime-select intel`, I get the Login Screen option to choose between X11 and Wayland. When I disable *Secure Boot* and choose `prime-select nvidia` I don't get an option to choose Wayland - I can only boot using X11. Not sure why this happens.

*My temporary workaround:* *Secure Boot* is currently always off (not great). By default, I have `prime-select nvidia` configured. When I want to use the laptop away from the dock for a long while, I configure `prime-select intel` and restart. Hoping this solution is super temporary.

Any ideas how to get the system to work consistently, with low power consumption except when using the GPU?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the internal connections of the gpu and the mainboard. I have a similar issue with a MSI GF65, but with a Lenovo E570 I have two displays connected in on-demand mode. I read that nvidia doesn't yet supports to act as a sink (pass the hdmi, display ports, etc to internal gpu) on intel or on-demand mode.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I think this is nto yet implemented in nvidia drivers ( https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/support-external-displays-in-render-offload-mode/107046/ ). It should work with nouveau drivers, but they do not power the nvidia GPU down so that does not help much (see powermanagement on this link: https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/Optimus.html ).

Answer (score 0):

As per https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/support-external-displays-in-render-offload-mode/107046/13, you need to install at least the 450.51 Beta proprietary Nvidia drivers: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/linux-solaris-and-freebsd-driver-450-51-beta/129482

And it should work. Note (see details in the first link) that the dGPU won't be powered off completely but will be in a low power mode when using external displays.